# Web services for DSC-WX300

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

Can I use the Camera Remote API for the DSX-WX300 also?
Or is this model using a different API? 
How can I take a photo remotely? It's possible I Know because the Play Memories Mobile App is doing this, but with the Remote API I only get HTTP 404 errors.

Please help me, I need this quite soon.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
But instead of using the url "http://10.0.0.1:10000/sony/camera" as mentioned in the API it has to be "http://10.0.0.1:10000/camera".